Show that $ \frac{S_n}{D_n} \xrightarrow{d} Y \sim N(0,1) \text{as } n \to \infty $ with CLT
Let $(X_n)$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$, be a sequence of iid variables with $\text{E}[X_1] = 0$ and $\text{Var}(X_1) = 1$.
Define the triangular array $(Z_{nk})$, ${1 \leq k \leq n, n \in \mathbb{N}}$, by $Z_{nk} := \sigma_{nk} X_k$, where $\sigma_{nk} \in (0, \infty)$ for $1 \leq k \leq n$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$ are real constants.
Define:
$
S_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n} Z_{nk}, \quad D_n^2 = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \sigma_{nk}^2.
$
Assume that
$
\frac{\max_{1 \leq k \leq n} \sigma_{nk}}{D_n} \to 0 \quad \text{as } n \to \infty.
$
Show that $
\frac{S_n}{D_n} \xrightarrow{d} Y \sim N(0,1) \quad \text{as } n \to \infty.
$
Hint: It can be used without proof that for a random variable $X$ with $\mathbb{E}[|X|^2] < \infty$ and a sequence $(a_n)$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$ with $a_n \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$, it holds that
$
\text{E}\left[X^2 \cdot 1_{\{|X| > a_n\}}\right] \to 0 \quad \text{as } n \to \infty.
$

First Attempt/Idea:
I started by analyzing $ \frac{S_n}{D_n} $ using the given definitions. My main approach is to break the problem into two subproblems:

First Subproblem (Numerator Analysis):
The numerator is the sum $ S_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n} Z_{nk} $, and I want to show that this converges in distribution to a standard normal variable, $ Y \sim N(0,1) $, using the Lindeberg Central Limit Theorem (CLT).

Second Subproblem (Denominator Analysis):
The denominator is $ D_n = \sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^{n} \sigma_{nk}^2} $, and my idea is to show that this converges to 1 as $ n \to \infty $.


Once both subproblems are handled, I plan to apply Slutsky’s Theorem for multiplying random variables, which allows us to combine the convergence results of the numerator and denominator, ultimately proving the statement.
First Subproblem:
To apply the Lindeberg CLT to $ S_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n} Z_{nk} $:

Independence: The $ Z_{nk} $'s should be independent because $ X_n $ are independent by definition. This condition seems satisfied.
Mean: I calculated $ \mathbb{E}[Z_{nk}] = 0 $ as $ \mathbb{E}[X_n] = 0 $.
Variance: The variance of each $ Z_{nk} $ is $ \text{Var}(Z_{nk}) = \sigma_{nk}^2 $. Thus, the total variance of $ S_n $ is $ \text{Var}(S_n) = D_n^2 = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \sigma_{nk}^2 $.

The remaining condition is to verify the Lindeberg condition. This is where I got stuck, as I'm unsure how to properly show that the Lindeberg condition applies to the $ Z_{nk} $'s. If someone could help with this step, it would clarify the application of the theorem.
Second Subproblem:
I haven’t fully worked through this yet, but my idea is that $ D_n \to 1 $ as $ n \to \infty $. This would simplify the expression to $ \frac{S_n}{D_n} \to Y \cdot 1 = Y $, where $ Y \sim N(0,1) $.
Since $ D_n $ converges to a constant, I plan to use Slutsky's Theorem to justify multiplying the two results in distribution, thereby obtaining the final result.

Second attempt / idea:
Theorem (4.2.3 Lindeberg):
Let $\{X_{nk}$, $1 \leq k \leq n$, $n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ be a sequence of independent random variables on the probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ with the following properties:

Expectation: $\mathbb{E}[X_{nk}] = 0$.

Finite Variance: $0 < \sigma^2_{nk} = \text{Var}(X_{nk}) < \infty, \quad k \in \{1, \ldots, n\}$.

Normalization Condition: $\sum_{k=1}^n \sigma^2_{nk} = 1, \quad n \in \mathbb{N}$.


If, for every $\epsilon > 0$, the following Lindeberg Condition (LBC) holds:
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \mathbb{E} \left( X_{nk}^2 \cdot \mathbb{I}(|X_{nk}| > \epsilon) \right) = 0, 
$$
then it follows that:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n X_{nk} \xrightarrow{d} N(0,1).
$$
Applying the Lindeberg Theorem:
We define the sequence of random variables as follows:
$
Y_{nk} = \frac{\sigma_{nk} X_k}{D_n}.
$
Here, $ \{X_k\} $ are independent random variables with mean $\mathbb{E}[X_k] = 0$ and variance $\text{Var}(X_k) = 1$.

Expectation and Variance:

Expectation: Since $\mathbb{E}[X_k] = 0$, we have:

$$
   \mathbb{E}[Y_{nk}] = \frac{\sigma_{nk}}{D_n} \cdot \mathbb{E}[X_k] = 0.
   $$

Variance: The variance of $Y_{nk}$ is:

$$
   \text{Var}(Y_{nk}) = \left(\frac{\sigma_{nk}}{D_n}\right)^2 \cdot \text{Var}(X_k) = \frac{\sigma_{nk}^2}{D_n^2} .
   $$

Sum of Variance:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n \text{Var}(Y_{nk}) = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\sigma_{nk}^2}{D_n^2} = \frac{1}{D_n^2} \sum_{k=1}^n \sigma_{nk}^2 = 1.
$$


Lindeberg Condition (LBC):
We need to verify the Lindeberg condition:
$$
   \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \mathbb{E} \left( Y_{nk}^2 \cdot \mathbb{I}(|Y_{nk}| > \epsilon) \right) = 0.
   $$
Substituting $Y_{nk} = \frac{\sigma_{nk} X_k}{D_n}$ into the condition:
$$
   \sum_{k=1}^n \mathbb{E} \left( \frac{\sigma_{nk}^2 X_k^2}{D_n^2} \cdot \mathbb{I}\left(\left| \frac{\sigma_{nk} X_k}{D_n} \right| > \epsilon \right) \right).
   $$
Since $ \frac{D_n \epsilon}{\sigma_{nk}} \to \infty $ as $n \to \infty$, and $ \mathbb{E}[X_k^2] < \infty $, the Lindeberg condition is satisfied (see given hint and given properties).

Conclusion:
By Lindeberg's CLT, since the Lindeberg condition holds, the normalized sum converges to a standard normal distribution:


$$
\frac{S_n}{D_n} \xrightarrow{d} N(0,1).
$$

Thanks to anyone who helps in solving this problem! I really find it an interesting exercise to understand how to apply the Lindeberg Central Limit Theorem in this context. I would appreciate any feedback on my current attempt or any other approaches, and I hope we can come up with a good solution together.

Note that $S_n$ cannot converge to a random variable with distribution $\mathcal N(0, 1)$ (unless $\sigma_{nk} = 1$)

This is indeed where I've been struggling with my argumentation. To use the Lindeberg Central Limit Theorem, I need to establish that the sum of the variances from $ k=1 $ to $ n $ equals 1, specifically for $ Z_{nk} $. However, I find myself lacking concrete information about $ \sigma_{nk}^2 $ and how to derive that sum properly.

Put $Y_{nk} := \sigma_{nk}\frac{X_{k}}{\sqrt{D_n}}$. Since the sequence $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is independent, so is the triangular array $(Y_{nk})_{1\leq k\leq n,n\in\mathbb N}$ (the independence here is understood rowwise). Consider $$\tilde S_n := \sum_{k=1}^{n}Y_{nk}.$$ By assumption, $\frac{\max_{k=1}^n\sigma_{nk}^2}{D_n}\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow 0$. This implies that $$\tilde S_n\rightarrow Y$$ in distribution as $n\rightarrow\infty$, where $Y$ is a random variable with distribution $\mathcal N(0, 1)$, iff the Lindeberg condition holds, i.e.,\begin{align}\tag{LBC}\sum_{k=1}^n\operatorname E\left[Y_{nk}^2\cdot I_{\left\{Y_{nk}^2>\epsilon\right\}}\right]\rightarrow 0\end{align} as $n\rightarrow\infty$ for all $\epsilon>0$. Here $I_A$ denotes the indicator function of the set $A$, i.e., $I_A(x) = 1$ iff $x\in A$ and $I_A(x) = 0$ otherwise.
Proof that (LBC) holds. Let $\epsilon>0$. Observe that \begin{align}\tag{$\star$}\left\{Y_{nk}^2>\epsilon\right\} = \left\{X_k^2>\frac{D_n}{\sigma_{nk}^2}\epsilon\right\}\subseteq\left\{X_k^2>\frac{D_n}{\max_{k=1}^n\sigma_{nk}}\epsilon\right\}\end{align} as $X_k^2>\frac{D_n}{\sigma_{nk}^2}\epsilon\geq\frac{D_n}{\max_{k=1}^n\sigma_{nk}^2}\epsilon$ for $n\in\mathbb N$. Moreover, \begin{align*}\sum_{k=1}^n\operatorname E\left[Y_{nk}^2\cdot I_{\left\{Y_{nk}^2>\epsilon\right\}}\right] &= \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\sigma_{nk}^2}{D_n}\operatorname E\left[X_k^2\cdot I_{\left\{X_k^2>\frac{D_n}{\sigma_{nk}^2}\epsilon\right\}}\right] \\ &= \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\sigma_{nk}^2}{D_n}\operatorname E\left[X_1^2\cdot I_{\left\{X_1^2>\frac{D_n}{\sigma_{nk}^2}\epsilon\right\}}\right] \\ &\leq \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\sigma_{nk}^2}{D_n}\operatorname E\left[X_1^2\cdot I_{\left\{X_1^2>\frac{D_n}{\max_{k=1}^n\sigma_{nk}^2}\epsilon\right\}}\right] \\ &= \operatorname E\left[X_1^2\cdot I_{\left\{X_1^2>\frac{D_n}{\max_{k=1}^n\sigma_{nk}^2}\epsilon\right\}}\right], \end{align*} where the second line follows from the fact that the sequence $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is identically distributed, the third line follows from ($\star$), and the last line from $\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\sigma_{nk}^2}{D_n} = 1$.
By assumption $\frac{\max_{k=1}^n\sigma_{nk}^2}{D_n}\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow 0$, and therefore $\frac{D_n}{\max_{k=1}^n\sigma_{nk}^2}\rightarrow \infty$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$. Note that $(\{Y_{nk}^2>\epsilon\})_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is a decreasing (non-increasing) sequence of sets such that $I_{\{Y_{nk}^2>\epsilon\}} \rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$.
Since $X_{k}^2\cdot I_{\left\{Y_{nk}^2>\epsilon\right\}}\leq X_k^2$ and $\operatorname{Var}[X_k] = 1 < \infty$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$, the Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem applies. Thus, \begin{align*}\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\operatorname E\left[Y_{nk}^2\cdot I_{\left\{Y_{nk}^2>\epsilon\right\}}\right] &\leq \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\operatorname E\left[X_{k}^2\cdot I_{\left\{Y_{nk}^2>\epsilon\right\}}\right] \\ &= \operatorname E\left[X_{k}^2\cdot\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} I_{\left\{Y_{nk}^2>\epsilon\right\}}\right] \\ &= 0\end{align*} where the first line follows from ($\star$), the second line follows from Dominated Convergence.
